# If $G$ is a triangle-free and $\delta(G)$ is large, then $G$ is bipartite graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

> Show that every $n$-vertex triangle-free graph with minimum degree
> greater than $2n/5$ is bipartite.

First of all this result is vacuously true for $n=1,3,5$. For $n=2$ and $n=4$, it is trivially true since the desired graphs are $K_2$ and $K_{2,2}$.

We assume that $n\geq 6$ and $V(G)=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$. Since $\deg(v_1)>2n/5$, then take $v_2\in N(v_1)$ and consider $N(v_2)$ also.

It is easy to see that $N(v_1)$ and $N(v_2)$ are disjoint and independent sets. Moreover, $|V(G)\setminus (N(v_1)\sqcup N(v_2))|<n/5$.

1. Consider the most trivial case, when $V(G)\setminus (N(v_1)\sqcup N(v_2))=\varnothing$. Hence $V(G)=N(v_1)\sqcup N(v_2)$ and $G$ is a bipartite graph with vertex sets $N(v_1)$ and $N(v_2)$ , i.e. $G=G[N(v_1),N(v_2)]$.

2. If $|V(G)\setminus (N(v_1)\sqcup N(v_2))|=1$, then $V(G)= N(v_1)\sqcup N(v_2)\sqcup \{w\}$.
   If $N(w)\cap N(v_1)=\varnothing$ or $N(w)\cap N(v_2)=\varnothing$, then $G$ is bipartite graph. Indeed, assume WLOG that $N(w)\cap N(v_1)=\varnothing$, then $G$ is a bipartite with vertex sets $N(v_1)\sqcup \{w\}$ and $N(v_2)$.

**Question 1.** What if $|N(w)\cap N(v_1)|=k>0$ and $|N(w)\cap N(v_2)|=\ell>0$? I sketched a picture and I see that $G$ is not bipartite in this case. I was wondering how to prove it rigorously?

**Question 2.** I was wondering is it possible to solve the problem with that approach? It seems a bit difficult to me but I did not checked the details since I stucked in question 1.

Comment: You say the result fails for $n=1,2,3$. How does it fail?

Comment: @Arthur, I mean that it is vacuosly true for these values of $n$.

Comment: Not vacuously. Well, for $n=1,3$ it holds vacuously, but not for $n=2$. There it holds because the only such graph is $K_2=K_{1,1}$. And I think you should correct the word "fails" the main post regardless.

Comment: @Arthur, good point! Edited. Thank you.

Comment: Where did you get this problem from?

Comment: @Mike, Exercise 1.1.6 from Yufei Zhao's book "Graph THeory and Additive combinatorics".

Answer (score 2):

This is not really answering your questions, but I'd like to suggest a possibly less complicated way of solving this exercise.

Let $G$ be a triangle-free simple graph of order $n$ with $\delta(G)\gt2n/5$, and assume for a contradiction that $G$ is not bipartite. Let $k$ be the length of a shortest odd cycle in $G$ (so $k\ge5$) and let $C$ be a cycle in $G$ of length $k$. Let $M=V(G)\setminus V(C)$ and $m=|M|$.

Since a vertex $v\in V(C)$ is joined to at most $2/5$ of the vertices in $C$, it must be joined to more than $2/5$ of the vertices in $M$, i.e., $|N(v)\cap M|\gt2m/5$. Hence, if $x$ is the number of edges between $V(C)$ and $M$, then $x\gt2mk/5\ge2m$. It follows that some vertex $w$ in $M$ must have at least $3$ neighbors in $C$. But now we can use $w$ to create an odd cycle of length less than $k$.

Comment: Nice solution! May I ask you dumb question (probably): if $k$ is the length of a shortest odd cycle so it means that $k$ is an odd number. Obviously $k\neq 3$ since the graph is triangle-free.  Hence $k=1$ or $k\geq 5$. What if $k=1$?

Comment: I assume $G$ is a *simple* graph, so there can be no cycles of length $\lt3$. The result would be false for non-simple graphs. Take any triangle-free non-bipartite graph, say $C_5$; you can make $\delta(G)$ arbitrarily large by adding loops or multiple edges.

Comment: Yeah, $G$ is supposed to be a simple graph. Also I guess when we define the cycle of length $k$ we assume that $k\geq 3$, right? I mean there is no sense of talking a cycle of length $<3$. Does it make sense?

Comment: A cycle of length $k$ has $k$ vertices and $k$ edges. A cycle of length $2$ has $2$ vertices joined by $2$ edges. A cycle of length $1$ has a single vertex and an edge joining that vertex to itself (a loop). In a simple graph, a cycle must lave length at least $3$.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! Indeed, in a simple graph we can talk only about a cycle of length $k\geq 3$.